# Tableau Data Blend Performance/ Level of Detail

Tags: performance, tableau-api, blend

I have two blended sources where the source A has 500,000 rows and source B has 20,000. The problem is that when I use source A as the primary source, any computation in the dashboard takes far too long to be useful. When I use B as my primary source, performance is much improved...

...but, the level of detail I need is in source A. When source B is primary I am left with the dreadful asterisk where there is a one-to-many relationship.

**Source A primary:**

```
Event(from source B)  Occurred_On(from source A)
    ABC                      1/1/2000
    ABC                      5/10/2000
    XYZ                      9/9/2002
    XYZ                      4/5/2002
```

**Source B primary:**

```
Event(from source B)  Occurred_On(from source A)
    ABC                      *
    XYZ                      *
```

Data must be blended-- source A is a database and source B is a text file so a join is out of the question.

Patience is waning and all hope seems to be lost. Does there exist any possible way to use B as the primary while maintaining the level of detail from a field in A?

Or any other workaround that could solve this?

Comment: What are your data sources? Text, Excel, SQL, etc? Are you using extracts? Which version of Tableau are you running?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness-- one is from an Oracle database and the other is a text file. Both are Tableau data extracts. Tableau version is 9.3.

Comment: If you are able to upgrade to version 10, you would be able to take advantage of joining data sources. If not, can you import the data from the text file into your Oracle database?

Comment: Version 10 saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the below options

- Cross database joins [a link] (http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/7/integrate-your-data-cross-database-joins-56724)

-Create a lookup table of the text file and apply a join [a link](https://community.tableau.com/thread/121361)

-To improve the performance, create a data extract file of the combined dataset which will be the primary data source for the report [a link] (http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#extracting_data.html)

Just, 500K record should not cause the performance drag but will be a good idea to recheck the server configuration and see if there are any bottlenecks.